# Side by side boxes: how to make one slide underneath?

Tags: css

Imagine two boxes side by side.
The right one is floated right, fixed width holding a photo, and the left contains text so fills any remaining width to the left edge of the container.

If I resize (squash down) the browser I want the text in the left box to be fluid. OK so far so good...

Here's the difficult part:
I need a minimum width on the left container, so when that is reached, the text box stops reducing, and right photo box starts sliding underneath the left box until it disappears.
Is this possible?

Any help appreciated!

Comment: A [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) with your code showing what you've done so far would be good :)

Comment: Also, by "sliding underneath the left box" mean that the left box _overlaps_ the right box?

Comment: Yes overlapping. Sorry - I haven't got any simple code as I've been trying just about every combination I can think of and I'm in a bit of a mess now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve a `z-index` overlapping with positioning, but you cannot with floating. You'll have to do something like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/jphB2/

**Code and inline explanation:**

```
.leftbox {
    position: relative; /* stay sort of in the document flow */
    z-index: 2; /* be positioned at level 2 */
    min-width: 200px; /* minimum width at which to stop getting smaller */
    margin-right: 200px; /* catering for that right column */
    background-color: rgba(155, 155, 255, 0.8); /* slightly transparent so we can see the right box go 'underneath' it */
}

.rightbox {
    position: absolute; /* remove from the document flow */
    right: 0; /* sit where we want it to */
    top: 0; /* sit where we want it to */
    z-index: 1; /* be positioned at level 1, so below level 2 */
    width: 200px; /* set a width */
    background-color: rgba(255, 155, 155, 0.8); /* uhh, colours are nice */
}
```

Comment: Setting the margin-right to 'protect' the right side box was the missing piece of my puzzle! Very many thanks setek!

Comment: @MrCat no problem :) if this answers your question could you mark it answered? Cheers :)